# What else is needed to setup an alarm in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that schedules an alarm at a certain time in which the user is suppose to take their medication. I have done everything that most guides and the documentation say it's required to setup the alarm. Here is the method I call when the user presses the button:

```
 private void scheduleAlarm() {
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarmeID, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmeTime.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
 }
```

Here is the AlarmReceiver.class

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
    ringtone.play();
}
```

}

and I have put these two lines in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
 <receiver android:name=".services.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

And yet, my application is not working. The alarm doesn't go off. What am I doing wrong? What else is needed?

Comment: you want to cancel the alarm?

Comment: No, I'm trying to put an alarm to ring in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently playing alarm ringtone from BroadcastReceiver. Instead of doing that, you can open an Activity and start playing alarm tone from there. You can use [stop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html#stop()) method to stop it (may be from button click within the activity).

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //start activity
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

**NextActivity.class**

//Start your ringtone here

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
    ringtone.play();

    //Somewhere inside button click
{
    ringtone.stop();
}
```

> Just copy pasting this won't work. I believe you can take concept from
>   here and implement as per your requirement.

And currently there is no any related code that will stop your ringtone.

Comment: Are there any other things that would prevent me from doing that? It's just not working. I'm trying in two virtual devices (API 17 and 25) and neither is working.

Comment: Neither worked at first, but now it is working, the problem is that the alarm goes off the second I set it, it doesn't wait the time it should.

Comment: @MarxGuimarães For this thread/question I think the problem is solved. Please create a new question to go with new problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not really sure wither you are asking how to stop the alarm ? or that the alarm is not working at all after the user presses the button but anyhow.
I replaced The alarm with a repeated alarm and launched it using onCreate method and I closed the app and waited for the alarm to go off and it did! 
And here is my code just in case:

```
        private void scheduleAlarm() {
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueID, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10000, pIntent);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, 1000, pIntent);
}
```

Everything else I copied and pasted from your code above. 
Edit: If you are seeking the repeated alarm then this the page to go to:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
note: my virtual device API is 24

Answer (score -1):

Change the code as below -

```
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60, pIntent);
```

May be your alarmeTime.getTimeInMillis() is not properly set. You can try the above line. It fires an alarm after 1 min.